# requestImageData was deprecated in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this depreciation message in my my project:

> `requestImageData(for:options:resultHandler:)` was deprecated in iOS 13

What is the most updated method to fix this?

```
func convertImageFromAsset(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage? {
    
    var img: UIImage?
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.version = .original
    options.isSynchronous = true
    manager.requestImageData(for: asset, options: options) { data, _, _, _ in
        
        if let data = data {
            img = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    return img
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As it [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/1616957-requestimagedataforasset) in the documentation, you should use [`requestImageDataAndOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/3237282-requestimagedataandorientation) - it has the same API, I think this is just a renaming done for better readability.

```
manager.requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: asset, options: options) { data, _, _, _ in
    if let data = data {
        img = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
```